# missing return in a function expected to return 'Double' | What to do?

Tags: swift, return

Following code:

```
protocol ExampleProtocol {
    var simpleDescription: String { get }
    var absoluteValue: Double { get }
    mutating func adjust()
}

extension Double: ExampleProtocol {
    var simpleDescription: String {
        return "The number \(self)"
    }
    var absoluteValue: Double {
        if self < 0 {
            return self * -1
        } else if self > 0 {
            return self
        }
    }
    mutating func adjust() {
        self += 42
    }
}
```

When trying to execute it with either simpleDescription or absoluteValue (e.g. print(10.simpleDescription), I just get this error:

> missing return in a function expected to return 'Double'

The absoluteValue "function" returns itself, so the Double value, so why is it saying it's missing one?

Comment: Think about the case where `self == 0`.

Comment: You probably just want to change `else if self > 0` to just `else`.

Comment: @rmady thanks a lot - added a else { return 0 }, but how could I write an else if self == 0? Because if I add "else if self == 0", it throws me an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your `if` statement is missing an `else` block, the return value is not defined for the case when `self == 0`. You can simply change the `else if` branch to `else`, because you also want to return `self` for `0`.

```
var absoluteValue: Double {
    if self < 0 {
        return self * -1
    } else {
        return self
    }
}
```

You can also write this as a oneliner using the ternary operator:

```
var absoluteValue: Double {
    return self < 0 ? self * -1 : self
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you also know an idea how to have if self < 0, else if self > 0, else and else if == 0? Because when I add the else if == 0 into the function, it doesn´t work.

Comment: @DoakCode why would you want to do that? The else block exactly covers that case. The compiler simply cannot determine that those `else if` blocks cover all possible values, hence the need for the `else`

Comment: Sure, but what if I would be in the need of a third case where self equals a certain number, like else if == 0? How would that work?

Comment: @DoakCode `if-else` blocks always need to be mutually exclusive and cover all possible cases if you want to directly return from them. So you'd need to add an `else` block in that case as well.

Comment: No, I mean if for e.g. for the number "5" and "0" is a special case, so I use if self > 5, else if == 5, else if < 0. How would such if-else block would look like?

Comment: @DoakCode then you didn't handle the case `self < 5 || self >= 0`, so you'd need an `else` block to handle that. You can have however many `else if` blocks you want, that wan't your issue...

Comment: Okay, given I added the else block, still I get an error for else if == 5 and else if == 0, but we covered self > 5, self < 5 || self >= 0, self < 0.

Comment: @DoakCode you still need an `else` block as I've already stated... `if self > 5 {
            return "Greater than 5"
        } else if self == 5 {
            return "5"
        } else if self < 0 {
            return "Less than 0"
        } else {
            return "rest"
        }` compiles just fine assuming you want to return a `String`.

Comment: Thanks, well somehow I´ve had problems with else if self == 5, my runtime threw an error, but think I made another error in this context. Anyways, thanks a lot for your help :)